# Extract first row numbers of row adress using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an empty Excel spreadsheet in which I defined a variable `Row` in the `name manager`. 
This variable currently refers to `3:3` but can switch any time. 
 
Therefore, it could also be `105:105` or `5000:5000` or any other number possible.

Now I use the following VBA to extract the **first numbers** of the **row adress**:

```
Sub Extract_Row_Adress()
    If Len(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)) <= 3 Then
        RowNumber = Mid(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), 1, 1)
    Else
        If Len(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)) <= 5 Then
            RowNumber = Mid(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), 1, 2)
        Else
            If Len(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)) <= 7 Then
                RowNumber = Mid(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), 1, 3)
            Else
                If Len(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)) <= 9 Then
                    RowNumber = Mid(Sheet1.Range("Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), 1, 4)
                Else
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Sheet1.Range("A5").Value = RowNumber
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

As you can see in the VBA I need to use several `IF statements` because the first numbers of the **row adress** can vary in their number of digits. According to this I have to adjust the lengths of the `Mid` function with `( 1, 1) ( 1, 2) ( 1, 3) ( 1, 4)` and so on.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this without having all this `If statements` running?

Comment: You should read about what a [ElseIf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement) statement is.

Comment: You should use `Split(variable, ":")(0)` , that will give you your answer straight. No need for If or Else or Simple `Sheet1.Range("Row").Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the row number

```
Sheet1.Range("Row").Row
```

If `Range("Row")` is eg `"4:6"` then

```
Sheet1.Range("Row").Row 'returns 4
Sheet1.Range("Row").Row + Sheet1.Range("Row").Rows.Count - 1 'returns 6
```

Comment: Very efficient. I broke my neck with a select case code (deleted it, cause it wouldn't work). Sometimes it's plain simple.

Comment: I was Writing this in an Answer. :) ... Simple as That.

Comment: When I run the code Sheet1.Range("Row").Row I get error Invalid Use of Property for .row

Comment: @Michi are you sure a named range `"Row"` does exist in `Sheet1`? Test it with `Sheet1.Range("4:6").Row` and you will see it works. • If your issue persists please tell the output of `Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("Row").Address`.

Comment: If use Sheet1.Range("4:6").Row I still get the same error. Debug.Print for Sheet1.Range("4:6").Row gives me $4:$6 and Debug.Print for Sheet1.Range("Row") gives me $4:$4 so all this seems correct. I even restarted my computer but the problem persists. I will try at a different PC later and see if it works there.

Comment: @Michi That is strange I tested the code and it works properly. Test in a new workbook.

Comment: After I restarted my PC again it is working now with RowNumber = Sheet1.Range("Row").Row. Thanks a lot for your help.